# Nilpotent element $a^2$ in a polynomial quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, irreducible-polynomials

$\textbf{Problem Statement : }$ Let $R : = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and let $I$ be the ideal $I = R \cdot(x^{17} -1)$  Is there a non-zero element a of the quotient ring $A = R/I$ such that $a^2 = 0$?

I do not believe there is, as if there was, then $a^2$ would have to be contained within the ideal. However $x^{17} -1$ is reducible and is equal to $(x-1)(\sum_{i=0}^{16} x^i)$, which are both irreducible so there can be no element $a \notin I$ but $a^2 \in I$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: By $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z[x]$ you mean $\Bbb Z_2[x]$, right?  That is, $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z[x] = (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)[x] = \Bbb Z_2[x]$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct @RobertLewis

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying,  Cheers!